# Java multithreading :Start 2 threads, print 1-100 by turns. result like this: but it is not running

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized, java-threads

Two threads needs to print in this order-

```
Thread1:0    
Thread2:::0    
Thread1:1    
Thread2:::1    
Thread1:2    
Thread2:::2    
Thread1:3    
Thread2:::3
Thread1:::4    
Thread2:::4    
.    
.    
.   
Thread1:100    
Thread2:::100
...
```

Currently this is my code, somehow it gets stuck. . Not sure why it is not running as expected

```
public class Solution{
    private volatile boolean isOneTurn;

    public Solution(){
        isOneTurn = true;
    }

    public void test(){
        Thread t1 = new Thread(new MyThread1("Thread1"));
        Thread t2 = new Thread(new MyThread2("Thread2"));

        t1.start();
        t2.start();
    }

    class MyThread1 implements Runnable {
        public String name;

        public MyThread1(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
        @SneakyThrows
        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
                synchronized (this) {
                    if (!isOneTurn){
                        this.wait();
                    }

                    System.out.println(name + "-" + i);
                    isOneTurn = false;
                    this.notifyAll();
                }
            }
        }
    }


    class MyThread2 implements Runnable {
        public String name;

        public MyThread2(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
        @SneakyThrows
        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
                synchronized (this) {
                    if (isOneTurn){
                        this.wait();
                    }

                    System.out.println(name + "-" + i);
                    isOneTurn = true;
                    this.notifyAll();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I know there are many similar question out there. But I am just wondering why my code is not working as expected.

Comment: code quality:  Both class could be reduced in one. Passing a different boolean to each instance for the 2 lines where the code differ

Comment: I'm going to guess that having your `wait` inside the synchronized block is the issue.  Essentially you've executed blocking code while holding the lock.

Comment: @DaveB You are only allowed to call `wait` while holding the lock, otherwise an `IllegalMonitorStateException` is thrown, see the documentation of [`Object.wait`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#wait(long,int))

Answer (score 5):

If you use wait and notify, a thread that waits needs to be able to expect another thread to call notify on the SAME OBJECT INSTANCE  that wait was called on. You’re not doing that, one thread synchronizes on an instance of Thread1 and the other instance synchronizes  on an instance of Thread2. The result is the threads enter wait and nothing wakes them up.

For locking to work the lock has to be shared. The wait and notify methods use the implicit lock being synchronized on as a coordination point, when a thread calls notify on the object synchronized on, only threads that called wait on that object can be woken up.

Answer (score -1):

Because you are using a
new Thread(new MyThread1("Thread1"));

In family guy term.  Plagio di plagio

Remove the "new Thread" and just use

Thread t1 = new MyThread1("Thread1");

Also, why Runnable and not callable and then print?

Comment: The OP wants to run separate threads, so they need to use `new Thread` (or an `ExecutorService` if they want to run concurrently. In this case, `Runnable` is the appropriate type for `MyThread1` (do that name is a bit of misnomer).

Comment: But to run separate threads as you mentioned it's better to use ExecutorService and work with Future not running two threads and block the way with the syncronize and the wait inside... :/

Maybe something with notify or another strategy in thread1 that transfer the value when it ends to thread2 with notifyAll() :/

Comment: Given the OP seems to be experimenting with basic synchronization and wait/notify between threads, using an executor service is not really necessary (and may even be problematic if the service has less threads than needed). Using futures makes no sense because there is no value produced here, and wouldn't show to turn taking between threads.